# How to create a bash file allowing a folder from CD be transferred to Documents?

Tags: 12.04, installation, bash, transfer

i want to transfer the myfiles folder from CD to Documents in a more decent way of transferring. I think creating an executable bash file is better. this bash file when clicked will allow the transfering of files. How will I create this?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just open up two file manager windows and drag the folder from one to the other? Writing a script would take more work, since you'd have to work out the mount point's name, which I think is derived from the CD's label, and use that. It could be done, but I don't think there'd be to much of a benefit to doing so.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use script for that, then write a script like that:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Transferring myfiles folder from CD to Documents..."
cp /media/(((CD Name)))/myfiles /home/(((username)))/Documents
echo "Transferred Successfully"
```

All done.

Answer (score 0):

The following bash script detects the mount point of the **first** CD/DVD drive and copies the `myfiles` folder to the `Documents` folder. If a folder `Documents/myfiles` exists already, the contents will be merged. Files with equal name will be overwritten.

```
#!/bin/bash
MOUNTPOINT=$(df | grep "/dev/sr" | head -n 1 | sed -e "s/.*%\s*\(.*\)/\1/g")
cp -r "$MOUNTPOINT/myfiles" "$HOME/Documents"
```

If, however, you want to **update** the contents of the two folders regularly, you are probably better off using `rsync` instead of `cp`, for example like this:

```
rsync -rtu --delete "$MOUNTPOINT/myfiles" "$HOME/Documents"
```

If you want to use `rsync`, you should consider the help page via `rsync --help`.